# How to get the center item after RecyclerView snapped it to center?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, snapping

I'm implementing a horizontal `RecyclerView` that snap items to center after scrolling, like Google play App horizontal lists. [This](https://rubensousa.github.io/img/snap_googleplay.webm) is a review.

My code is below:

```
MainMenuAdapter mainMenuAdapter = new MainMenuAdapter(this, mDataset);

final LinearLayoutManager layoutManagaer = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView mainMenu = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_menu);
mainMenu.setLayoutManager(layoutManagaer);
mainMenu.setAdapter(mainMenuAdapter);

final SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mainMenu);
```

How I can get the center item (position) after `RecyclerView` snapped it to center? Isn't there any listener implementation for this?
Also, when an item view be touched, I want to snap it to center. How can I do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

if you need the View, you can call

```
 View view =  snapHelper.findSnapView(layoutManagaer);
```

once you have the View, you should be able to get the position on the dataset for that View. For instance using

```
   mainMenu.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
```

Comment: A very clean solution. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

**Better to use this method:**

https://medium.com/over-engineering/detecting-snap-changes-with-androids-recyclerview-snaphelper-9e9f5e95c424

**Original post:**
Even if you are not going to use `SnapHelper` you can get the central element position by `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`.

1. Copy `MiddleItemFinder` class to your project.
2. Create callback object `MiddleItemCallback`.

   ```
   MiddleItemFinder.MiddleItemCallback callback = 
           new MiddleItemFinder.MiddleItemCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void scrollFinished(int middleElement) {
                       // interaction with middle item
                   }
   };
   ```
3. Add new scroll listener to your `RecyclerView`

   ```
   recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(
           new MiddleItemFinder(getContext(), layoutManager, 
                   callback, RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE));
   ```
4. The last parameter or `MiddleItemFinder` constructor is `scrollState`.

   - `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` – The RecyclerView is not currently 
     scrolling. Scroll finished.
   - `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` – The RecyclerView is currently 
     being dragged by outside input such as user touch input.
   - `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` – The RecyclerView is currently 
     animating to a final position while not under outside control.
   - `MiddleItemFinder.ALL_STATES` – All states together.
5. For example, if you choose `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` as the last constructor parameter than in the end of all scroll the callback object will return you the middle element position.

#### MiddleItemFinder class:

```
public class MiddleItemFinder extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    private
    Context context;

    private
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    private
    MiddleItemCallback callback;

    private
    int controlState;

    public
    static final int ALL_STATES = 10;

    public MiddleItemFinder(Context context, LinearLayoutManager layoutManager, MiddleItemCallback callback, int controlState) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.controlState = controlState;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

        if (controlState == ALL_STATES || newState == controlState) {

            int firstVisible = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastVisible = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            int itemsCount = lastVisible - firstVisible + 1;

            int screenCenter = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2;

            int minCenterOffset = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            int middleItemIndex = 0;

            for (int index = 0; index < itemsCount; index++) {

                View listItem = layoutManager.getChildAt(index);

                if (listItem == null)
                    return;

                int leftOffset = listItem.getLeft();
                int rightOffset = listItem.getRight();
                int centerOffset = Math.abs(leftOffset - screenCenter) + Math.abs(rightOffset - screenCenter);

                if (minCenterOffset > centerOffset) {
                    minCenterOffset = centerOffset;
                    middleItemIndex = index + firstVisible;
                }
            }

            callback.scrollFinished(middleItemIndex);
        }
    }

    public interface MiddleItemCallback {

        void scrollFinished(int middleElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: That medium article is very wholesome and clean!