# Android Horizontal scrollable slider with all menu items are visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I need to implement a horizontally scrollable slider, something like

Item1 is selected
[image: Item 1 is selected]

Item2 is selected
[image]

Item3 is selected
[image]

I tried to use both RecyclerView and HorizontalScrollView. But in both cases if all the items are visible, the view will not scroll anymore.

But I need to scroll the items so that the one in the center of the screen will be the selected option.
And the end of the list (first and last item of the list) should be scrolled till the middle of the screen only.

Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: You should look at this library, it has a feature something you want https://github.com/nshmura/RecyclerTabLayout

Comment: Also to keep scrolling once all items are shown you could either add invisible dummy items or add padding to your recyclerview.

Comment: This is what I was looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510142/1554537